# responds to selector but throws error

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

```
- (void)TargetHit:(int)target{

    void (^threadBlock)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"respond to selector %d", [self respondsToSelector:@selector(changeImageOfTarget:)]);

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeImageOfTarget:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:target] waitUntilDone:YES];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]; 
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeImageOfTarget:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:target] waitUntilDone:YES];
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), threadBlock);
}
```

I can understand why my code returns `YES` to responds to selector but when I try and perform it I get an error message and the app crashes.

```
[NSOperationQueue changeImageOfTarget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a39810'
```

It's also the same for

```
 [[NSThread currentThread] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeImageOfTarget:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:target] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

How am I able to perform a method or `@selector` on the main thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self`might responde to the selector. The problem is that `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`doesn't.

> How am I able to perform a method or @selector on the main thread?

Just call it on the object where you want the action to be performed:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeImageOfTarget:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:target] waitUntilDone:YES];
```